# ChromeExtension: trigger a listener on google search

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What is the best way to trigger a listener in a chrome extension that fires whenever a user searches in chrome? The best idea I have right now is

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'loading' && tab.active) {
        let tabURL = new URL(tab.url)
        // handler code here
    }
}
```

However, this sometimes ends up with the query completing and the search results page showing, and then the code executing. I want to transform the query before it has a chance to be sent to google's servers. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You can redirect the URL itself to a modified string by using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest, see the documentation and examples. Alternatively you can run a content script that listens to `input` event on `document` and then processes the search box element.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do this:

in `manifest.json`

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "blockingwebRequest",
    "*://*.google.com/"
],
```

in background.js

```
      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
          // code here
        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking"]);
```